# not type argument for interface adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

please help me, I can't implement Kotlin in RecyclerView. I want to make an adapter for my application using RecyclerView but when I implement  (), then I get an error.

Here is my code:

```
class HomeAdapter(private val results: List<Result>) : Adapter<HomeAdapter.HomeViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): HomeViewHolder {
        return HomeViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater
                .from(parent.context)
                .inflate(
                    R.layout.item_home,
                    parent, false
                )
        )
    }

    override fun onBindBiewHolder(holder: HomeViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(results[holder.adapterPosition])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return results.count()
    }

    inner class HomeViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun bind(result: Result) {
            with(itemView) {
                val title = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_title)
                title.text = result.title

                val overview = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_overview)
                overview.text = result.overview
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error:

[image: Screenshot of error popup on a portion of code in Android Studio]

Comment: Change it to `RecyclerView.Adapter`

Answer (score -1):

Import the correct adapter class for your purpose:

```java
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

class HomeAdapter(...) : RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeAdapter.HomeViewHolder>() {...}
```

You must have been importing the `android.widget.Adapter` which was causing the error.

Comment: The `No type argument` error was thrown because Adapter he was importing doesn't has generics, which implied he was importing the `android.widget.Adapter`

Comment: I have already imported it, why is it still error. Please help me

Comment: @Misbagas imported `import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` and changed Adapter with `RecyclerView.Adapter`?

Comment: @Misbagas did you got the solution?

Comment: @Misbagas if the answer solved your problem then please mark it as accepted by clicking on the green tick mark on the left side of the answer!

Comment: @Misbagas can you please mark answer as accepted by clicking on accept tick mark? as it solved your problem...